# ChromeDriver not waiting on `get()`?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The JavaDoc of `WebDriver.get()` says `... the method will block until the load is complete.`

Firefox driver waits until all initial JavaScript has finished. However, ChromeDriver seems to return as soon as the HTML is downloaded. This makes testing JS-based web apps difficult as you don't even know if the app is rendered or not when the function returns.

Does anyone know if this is the expected behavior and if so how to check if JavaScript has finished running?

Comment: I test large applications (hundreds of tests) in Selenium across Firefox, Chrome and IE and have no problem testing JavaScript applications. Please give a reproducible case so that the answers you get are not just a bunch of wild guesses or bad advice (like the one answer you've already gotten).

Answer (score 0):

We have found with selenium, that putting lots of sleeps between steps solves about 95 percent of problems, and is about the only reliable way to deal with these issues. It makes for slow tests, but really, if you are emulating the browser, it's that slow in the real world as well. Rather than spend tons of time trying to trouble shoot every delay, put in a wait/sleep, and continue on.

Comment: That's the worst approach ever. Nobody never should put sleep in their application.

Comment: If it's testing, which is mostly what selenium is used for, it doesn't much matter. You are just emulating a delay. If you are running it on a box with a lot of other apps, not so good. But saying that you should never use a sleep, ever, is kind of one of those coding religion things, like whether to drop down the bracket to the line below the function start. We are in the middle of writing a few hundred testing scripts. We are testing that the app functions. It's completely immaterial whether we use sleep or not. If that's so for the OP, then why waste the time.

Comment: Come on, it's not religious things. It's just practical things that are really matters while you have more then 1 test. Sleep is unusable in most circumstances, you can't know if that much sleep is sufficiant or not, you will loose a lot of time if you will have ANY workflow that include automated UI testing. It's a waste of your future time to use sleeps in your current tests.

Comment: You could set up an implicit wait to avoid typing sleep and that will likely increase the testing speed as the test will continue as soon as the element is available. If you want to wait for a specific time you can just set up an explicit time for the chosen element.

Comment: The [module selenium-webdriver/lib/promise](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html) should make sleeps useless, isn't it?